# "Array to string conversion" i want to connect and make relation from 2 database but i dont really know how the correct condition

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database, eloquent

i take data from 'clickhouse' and i store it with foreach array. Afterward, i try to take data from 'sakiladb' which has same condition with data from 'clickhouse' which i stored before [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDtOE.png)

```
    $factpelanggan = DB::connection('clickhouse')
        ->select('SELECT t.id_tahun, t.tahun, l.id_lokasi
    from dim_tahun t, dim_lokasi l');

    foreach ($factpelanggan as $value) {
        $id_tahun[] = $value['id_tahun'];
        $id_lokasi[] = $value['id_lokasi'];
        $tahun[] = $value['tahun'];
    }


    $factpelanggan2 = DB::connection('sakiladb')
    ->select("SELECT YEAR(ren.rental_date) as YEAR , negara.country , count(customer_id) as jml_pelanggan
    from rental ren 
    where negara.country_id = $id_lokasi
    inner join inventory inven on ren.inventory_id = inven.inventory_id 
    inner join store toko on inven.store_id = toko.store_id
    inner join address alamat on toko.address_id =alamat.address_id
    inner join city kota on alamat.city_id =kota.city_id
    inner join country negara on kota.country_id = negara.country_id
    group by year(ren.rental_date) , negara.country 

    ");
```

[Error Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDtOE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring $id_locasi as an array but you are tying to select a single value in where condition. That's why the error is showing. You can try in following way.

```
$factpelanggan2 = DB::connection('sakiladb')
    ->select("SELECT YEAR(ren.rental_date) as YEAR , negara.country , count(customer_id) as jml_pelanggan
    from rental ren 
    where negara.country_id In ( implode(',',$id_lokasi))
    inner join inventory inven on ren.inventory_id = inven.inventory_id 
    inner join store toko on inven.store_id = toko.store_id
    inner join address alamat on toko.address_id =alamat.address_id
    inner join city kota on alamat.city_id =kota.city_id
    inner join country negara on kota.country_id = negara.country_id
    group by year(ren.rental_date) , negara.country 

    ");
```

Comment: the output has the same error, sir

Comment: There was a typo in my query, I have edited that. Can you try now?

Comment: sorry, sir. Its still the same |
i've been try to modify my code also in other ways, but still the same |
i mean, is it really possible sql-query with condition from (another) array?

Answer (score 0):

you are using where condition  with array in query, that`s why you get this error
change you code to this :

```
 $factpelanggan = DB::connection('clickhouse')
    ->select('SELECT t.id_tahun, t.tahun, l.id_lokasi
from dim_tahun t, dim_lokasi l');

foreach ($factpelanggan as $value) {
    $id_tahun[] = $value['id_tahun'];
    $id_lokasi[] = $value['id_lokasi'];
    $tahun[] = $value['tahun'];
}

$str_id_lokasi = implode(',',$id_lokasi);

$factpelanggan2 = DB::connection('sakiladb')
->select("SELECT YEAR(ren.rental_date) as YEAR , negara.country , count(customer_id) as jml_pelanggan
from rental ren 
where negara.country_id In $str_id_lokasi
inner join inventory inven on ren.inventory_id = inven.inventory_id 
inner join store toko on inven.store_id = toko.store_id
inner join address alamat on toko.address_id =alamat.address_id
inner join city kota on alamat.city_id =kota.city_id
inner join country negara on kota.country_id = negara.country_id
group by year(ren.rental_date) , negara.country 

");
```